# singleton inheritance from a base class

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, singleton

Tech: Python 3.11.2

```py
from mylogging import MyLogging


class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.logger = MyLogging(logName=self.__class__.__name__)

# Singleton
class ChildSingletonClass(BaseClass):
    __instance = None

    def __new__(cls):
        if cls.__instance is None:
            cls.__instance = super(ChildSingletonClass, cls).__new__(cls)

        return cls.__instance

    def __init__(self):
        self.logger.debug(f"{self} address = {id(self)}")
```

Have a `ChildSingletonClass` "singleton" class, that I now need to inherit from `BaseClass`, so I can take advantage of the inheritance goodness. But running into this error

```
    self.logger.debug(f"{self} address = {id(self)}")
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'ChildSingletonClass' object has no attribute 'logger'
```

I've tried changing `__new__` to call `super(BaseClass, cls)` instead, but that doesn't seem to help either.

Any ideas anyone? TIA

Comment: Usual solution would be to call `super ().__init__` from `ChildSingletonClass.__init__` (before using `self.logger`) if `self.logger` isn't already present.

Answer (score 1):

You are simply not calling the super() method in your `__init__`.

Adding a `super().__init__()` line in your childclass `__init__` will fix that.

However, there is an issue with the way Python works with `__new__` and `__init__` that might surprise you there: even though overrding `__new__` in this way won't create new instances, the `__init__` method will be called each time one tries to instantiate this class.

That can be fixed by changing `__new__` to return `cls.__instance` if it exists, but letting `__init__` itself populate the cached instance, and use it as a guard to break early if it already exists:

```
from mylogging import MyLogging


class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.logger = MyLogging(logName=self.__class__.__name__)

# Singleton
class ChildSingletonClass(BaseClass):
    __instance = None

    def __new__(cls):
        if cls.__instance is not None:
            return cls.__instance
        return super(ChildSingletonClass, cls).__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self):
        if cls.__instance is not None:
             return
        cls.__instance = self
        super().__init__()
        self.logger.debug(f"{self} address = {id(self)}")
```